# MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I want to create a stored procedure with input parameter like
num1, num2, operation, out parameter as result.

If you pass num1 = 1; num2 = 2; operation = add, then I need to get result as 3 via out parameter only.

Use function inside procedure for calculation.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE taskname(@num1 int, @num2 int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR

    SET @result = CAST ((num1 + @num2) AS INT)

    PRINT 'The sum of ' + CAST(@num1 AS INT) + ' and ' + CAST(@num2 AS INT) + ' is ' + CAST((@num1 + @num2) AS INT )

    PRINT @result
END
```

I have tried in this way.

Comment: What to do if the `operation=subtract` ?

Comment: Youve not even followed the first line of your homework: `Create one stored proc with input parameter like num1,num2,operation,out parameter as result.`

Comment: If we do your homework for you, what will you learn?

Comment: If you need to add (or subtract) two `INT` values - ***WHY*** is your `@result` a `VARCHAR` ??? Also: if you define a `VARCHAR` *without* an explicit length - it's a **ONE** character long string - typically **NOT** what you want. Furthermore: your `@num1` value already **IS** an `INT` - so why do you constantly do `CAST(@num AS INT)` - that's totally useless.....

Comment: Your title does *not* ask a question. Suggest you edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Create proc taskname(@num1 int, @num2 int,@operation nvarchar(max) ,@result int out)
    as
    begin
    if(operation = 'ADD')
BEGIN
    set @result = @num1 + @num2
    print 'the sum of '+cast(@num1 as nvarchar(max)) + ' and ' + cast(@num2 as nvarchar(max)) + ' is ' + cast(@result as nvarchar(max))
    print @result
END

 if(operation = 'SUB')
BEGIN
    set @result = @num1 - @num2
    print 'the subtraction of '+cast(@num1 as nvarchar(max)) + ' and ' + cast(@num2 as nvarchar(max)) + ' is ' + cast(@result as nvarchar(max))
    print @result
END

 if(operation = 'MUL')
BEGIN
    set @result = @num1 * @num2
    print 'the multiplication of '+cast(@num1 as nvarchar(max)) + ' and ' + cast(@num2 as nvarchar(max)) + ' is ' + cast(@result as nvarchar(max))
    print @result
END
    end
```

To excute procedure

```
    DECLARE @result int
    EXEC taskname 2 ,2,ADD,@result
```

OUTPUT:-

```
    the sum of 2 and 2 is 4
    4
```

Comment: what to do if operation for subtraction and multiplication?

Comment: i have updated my answer , is this what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: please mark it as answer if it is useful and correct